# Entity Framework Inheritance - determine object type

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an Entity Framework Model similar to this:

1. Person
2. Employee (Inherits Person)
3. Contact (Inherits Person)

I can Add,Query (Using OfType), and Update Employees and Contacts with no problem. However, I can not determine what type a Person object is. Say for example:

```
var person = entities.People.Single(p => p.Id == 5);
```

How can I do this:

```
if (person.IsEmployee){
//do something
} else if (person.IsContact) {
// do something else
}
```

Alternatively, I can settle for this:

```
if (person.IsOfType<Employee>()){
// do something
} else if (person.IsOfType<Contact>()) {
// do something else
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (person is Employee){
//do something
} else if (person is Contact) {
// do something else
}
```